# Does @backstage/plugin-api-docs display required properties in openapi document

Tags: backstage

Backstage UI is not displaying required properties in openapi document even though, i can see required properties in raw yaml. I am using defualt @backstage/plugin-api-docs .Is there a way to display required properties?